# mac doesnt boot after single user mode

Tags: error, startup

I had brought an external hard disk to use as a time machine. There was a problem while trying to partition, so i booted into single user mode and ran the ffsck command. This returned an error, and after that, my mac stopped rebooting. I tried many things, from safe mode to repairing in disk utility, but nothing works. All im getting when i try to boot is a progress bar that stops when its about 1/9 done, and then the computer shuts down.
What the hell happened?
I have no back ups whatsoever...

EDIT: is there a way i can somehow get the files off my hard disk using the same mac? I have no other computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fsck modified the filesystem, it may have corrected damage to the file system by deleting a file needed to boot.

If you can get professional troubleshooting assistance, I would do that since without a backup, you'd hate to make the problem worse.

Trying to fix a filesystem or writing new files to it will over-write space that could have files that you need to recover, so you'll want to shut down the computer and make a decision:

1. Are you willing to proceed without trying to recover the files you need?
2. Is it better to get a quote for data-recovery and learn more about the problem than it is to try to fix this now.

Good luck - I hate to be in this situation (either as the one giving advice or the one needing advice), but it's a problem that many have overcome, so you'll just need to figure out what's most important to you and be sure you understand what the consequences of doing a step might be. In your case, `fsck` isn't a good tool to run if you have precious data since it is designed to save a filesystem by making it sane after errors creep in. It's not designed to save individual files that have not been backed up.

Comment: Thank you for your input - it is really helpful. The files I'm trying to save aren't that much - is there any way I can somehow access or attempt backing up this hard disk to another hard disk? The only issue i'm having is that I don't have another computer, otherwise i would just use it to install osx on the external hard disk and use it as a boot up drive..

Comment: You didn't put nearly enough detail into the question for us to even guess what your options are. You could go to apple.com/support and work through the process of "which mac do you own?" / "Which version of OS was installed" / What happens when you boot to recovery? etc… and then ask a second question listing the specific article you ended up at and what you don't get. If you want, I'd also say - just ask a second question stating what you have and ask people to help with options. Just give a few words of detail so that people don't have to guess what you've tried and where you are at.

Comment: Point taken - my apologies. This is mostly because im having trouble typing on a tablet. Nevertheless, i have figured out a way to install osx on an external hardisk, which ill use to boot my computer and access my main hard disk. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good Luck. We optimize away from being the place to ask urgent troubleshooting problems and instead optimize for problems you've thought about for a while and can't get traction after doing some research.